# Value just available after second function call

Tags: swift, function, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function and it's working great but now I need the value out of the function to use it for another purpose.
But my problem is that I always have to execute the function twice to get a value in the outer part of the function (var valueOutOfFunction).

```
var valueOutOfFunction = [(String)]()
func loadQuery(com:@escaping( [(Int, String)] -> ())){ 
    var arrayOfTuples = [(Int, String)]() 
    db.collection("Data").whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1).whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 50).whereField("gender", isEqualTo: "F").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
                 for (index, document) in querySnapshot!.documents.enumerated() {
                 arrayOfTuples += [(index, document.documentID)]
                 }       
        }
        com(arrayOfTuples)
    } 
}
```

Then I am calling it here:

```
loadQuery { arr in 
  self.valueOutOfFunction = arr // Has a value in the first execution
}  

print (valueOutOfFunction) //Executing the first time there is no value in the variable, the second time it have a value.
```

Why is it just on the second attempt available and what could be a solution for this problem ?
Thanks!

Comment: Do know what asynchronous means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `valueOutOfFunction` is happening inside of that closure which is being called asynchronously to the print statement. Additionally, you are executing the completion *outside of the else statement* which may be firing before your for loop completes. What you want to do is control the flow from within the closure itself like so:

```swift
// move com(arrayOfTuples) up into the else block but outside of the for loop


func handleQuery() {
    loadQuery { doStuffWithResult($0) }
    // This line will run before the first line of doStuffWithResult
    // It would be best to end the function logic at loadQuery
}

func doStuffWithResult(_ arrayOfTuples: [(Int, String)]) {
    print(arrayOfTuples)
    // Do other work here
}
```

What you're looking into is control flow. You want to execute `X if Y` has occurred and `Z if !Y` right?

I would recommend looking into [swift's result type](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-result-types-in-swift/). This will help you manage control flow with closures.

An example:

```swift
typealias QueryResult = [(Int, String)]

enum QueryErrors: Error {
    case couldNotFind
}

func loadQuery(_ result: @escaping (Result<QueryResult, Error>) -> Void) {
    db.collection("Data").whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1).whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 50).whereField("gender", isEqualTo: "F").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents.enumerated() else {
            // I think enumerated will give you an array of tuples... if not add this to the end of that line. After enumerated but before else
            // enumerated().compactMap { ($0, $1) }
            result(.failure(err ?? QueryErrors.couldNotFind))// passes back Firebase error if it exists or default error if it doesn't
            return 
        } 
            result(.success(documents))
    }
}

// how it works 

loadQuery() { result in
    switch(result) {
    case .success(let arr): print(arr)
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```